# How to recreate functionality without violating software code copyright laws?

Tags: copyright, software

What would happen if I need to recreate code for a software function I did previously?

The catch is that even when I'm writing it from scratch I cannot make it very different from how it was where I originally did it because I know the design very well and so the new code would be very similar to original code.

Although there will be slight differences, the code would likely end up looking similar to original because its just the most efficient way to write that feature.

Otherwise I'd have to purposefully induce imperfections and scramble the names to illegibility just to avoid any possible copyright infringements.

Comment: An extreme example is the movie "Paycheck" (2003) based upon a Philip K. Dick short story.

Comment: "Scrambling" the names would not do anything anyway; if you compare the two versions (one with one set of names and one with the others), most likely anyone would consider one version to be a derivative work from the other.  Simply renaming variable names does not produce a new original creative work. The safest way would be to use a so-called "clean room approach" where you give the design, specifications, test cases, etc. (i.e. non code parts) to someone else without access to the original code and have her write a new version based upon those designs.

Comment: @Brandin What if you used a different computer language? Some substitutions might not be practical, but e.g. Rust and C have very similar syntax but very different memory usage patterns.

Comment: @Allahjane to clarify, you wrote the software before, but you don't own the copyright? For example because your employer owns the copyright instead?

Comment: @wimh more like i did independent work for a client that i routinely do and i learned a few techniques while doing it along with how to write best code for it.  So now when i am working on a different project and wish to use the same technique which would likely result in similar looking code because it's the best way to write it.

Comment: @simonatrcl Translating a program from one language to another would be considered a derivative work, so no it would not matter. If a program written in C is copyrighted, and then you rewrite it in Rust, then your 'new' Rust program is clearly a derivative of the original C program.

Comment: @Allahjane Using a 'technique' is not copyrightable. You can freely use any 'techniques', programming practices, algorithms, etc. that you learned. The only problem you might run into is copyrights (very unlikely if all you are using is a 'technique') or patents (possible if your specific 'technique' is something that is patented, but probably unlikely as well).

Comment: @Allahjane but when you did independent work for a client, you transferred the copyright of that work to that client in the contract? It is important, because if you still own the copyright of the original work, it can never be a copyright violation.

Comment: @Brandin "the only problem you'll run into is copyrights " yeah i guess that's what the question is about?

Comment: @wimh yes they have copyright over the code i wrote. However my question is how would any two similar software exist if the code is not allowed to be even similar. I mean it'd be like using your knowledge only once in your life and then get it locked behind copyright or purposely obfuscate it which is worse

Comment: @Allahjane Knowledge is not copyrighted, only the specific expression of it. For example a book about woodworking is copyrighted. But once you read that book and learn how to do woodworking, anything you make with that knowledge is generally your own. It's pretty much the same with computer code; as long as you don't actually copy code or derive code (such as "copying and simply renaming variables") from your earlier works which you did for hire, you don't have a problem with copyright.

Comment: If you write the software, make small commits to a git repository. That allows you to prove the steps you made to get to the result. Even if the result will show similarities, if you are able to demonstrate how you reached the end result, it will be clear that it is not copied from the previous work.

Comment: @Brandin well that is true,  but in this case as i said i know it all too well such that if i even guided someone to write it for me he'll end up writing essentially same code with slight differences like name changes.

Comment: @Allahjane As an answer below says look at the "clean room" approach if you want to avoid unintentionally copying code. Using knowledge or "guiding" someone is not copying. For example if you guide someone and say "here's how you can determine the tax rate" and then that person writes some code that calculates the tax rate, and it just so happens that her code is very similar (perhaps some names are different, etc.) to the code that you wrote months before, then most likely that simply means that that is the only logical way to solve that specific problem. It is not copying.

Comment: @Allahjane: Since you know the original environment, you presumably also know the code versioning system they used. You can not only show the evolution of your code, but in discovery you can also get the evolution of their code. Even if the end result is similar, the histories will differ (order of feature development, bugfixes, etc). This shows parallel development, proving it's not a derivative work.

Comment: @MSalters well the problem with that is it'll come in play in the court. It might not help with the ruckus that would happen until the case is finally in there. I wish there was a way to avoid the claim from happening in the first place without being forced to avoid the best practices and design that I've learnt

Comment: @Allahjane Programming (and writing) best practices do not have anything to do with copyright. Imagine a similar sitation - you are a nonfiction writer and you write a story (but the copyright belongs to your employer). Now you have a new employer and you want to write a similar story without copying the old one. Of course you can write with all the best practices you learned before, and you can write about the same subject matter as before; you can even use the same vocabulary you used before, but you cannot *copy* or derive what you wrote before. Using your 'practices' and 'knowledge' is OK.

Comment: @Brandin that is true, but that example only works because of the amount of freedom you have in a work of fiction. Meanwhile in programming you need code to perform an exact task that has been set as the goal. From all the ways one can write things like data structure and its handling to reach that goal , only one will be known as most efficient . If you try to write code for reaching that goal again for a different program you'd want to use that most efficient design of data structures again, which will make the code look similar, because that code defines the exact operations and data.

Comment: @Allahjane You may want to look for information on this site about scenes a faire and merger doctrine. If there is truly only one or a small number of ways of writing a piece of code, then the fact that two pieces of code look similar does not mean they are derivitives of each other.

Answer (score 3):

So you're trying to avoid a claim for copyright infringement.

As you know, the linchpin to copyright infringement is copying. If you don't copy the previous code that you refer to, you're not copying, and there can be no copyright infringement. That is a question of fact. If you don't have access to the previous source code, you can't copy it.

As you say the code is relatively simple, you could develop the code in a clean room (ie no previously developed code is accessible to you), and document the process as you do it.

That would probably reduce the prospects of someone coming to you later and succeeding in a claim for copyright infringement.

Comment: I'm simply trying to avoid copyright infringement without having my knowledge locked away behind a copyright such that I'd be forced to redo the same type of work with purposely obfuscated code or with inferior code

Comment: I don't think clean room programming is economically feasible except in very rare cases.

Comment: Using third party version control hosting like github could help prove code growth, am I right? As you cannot forge history that way.

Answer (score 2):

**(I'm not a lawyer. DO NOT rely on the content below as legal advice. Please consult an attorney for your serious business.)**

Since you said

> Although there will be slight differences, the code would likely end up looking similar to original because **it's just the most efficient way to write that feature**.

I will abstractly, without exploring into your factual circumstances, discuss the question of **whether, in implementing a specific feature, it infringes copyright to use copyrighted software code that is the most efficient way to implement that feature**. The discussion focuses on US copyright law.

(tl;dr; go to the bold paragraph at the bottom.)

#### Expression-Idea Dichotomy

Copyright only protects expression of ideas, but not the ideas themselves. For example, copying the content of a cookbook may result in copyright infringement, but simply cooking by following the procedure (idea) outlined in the cookbook generally does not infringe copyright. Simply speaking, by offering the authors limited-time protection over their expression, copyright is an engine that encourages people to generate expression. The ideas embodied in these expression, as implemented in the real world, benefits the society as a whole. Therefore, the purpose of copyright law, in some sense, is to encourage the implementation of ideas embodied in copyrighted expression.

#### Merger of Expression and Idea

But expression and ideas sometimes merge. When this happens, the idea (which has merged with its expression) is no longer protected by copyright law. For example, in [Baker v. Selden, 101 U.S. 99 (1879)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_v._Selden), Selden described a book-keeping system in his book, which includes certain blank forms. To use the book-keeping system in Selden's book, copying these blank forms is inevitable. The Court holded that there was no copyright infringement and explained:

> ... But this object
>   would be frustrated if the knowledge could not be used without incurring the guilt of
>   piracy of the book. And where the art it teaches cannot be used without employing the
>   methods and diagrams used to illustrate the book, or such as are similar to them, such
>   methods and diagrams are to be considered as necessary incidents to the art, and given
>   therewith to the public; not given for the purpose of publication in other works
>   explanatory of the art, but for the purpose of practical application...

#### Merger of Expression and Idea in Software Code

When there is only one or very few ways to (efficiently) implement a certain idea in computer programming, such as an algorithm, the expression (the software code) and the idea (e.g., the algorithm), may have merged. The court in [Computer Associates International, Inc. v. Altai, Inc., 982 F.2d 693 (2d Cir. 1992)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Associates_International,_Inc._v._Altai,_Inc.) explained:

> While, hypothetically, there might be a myriad of ways in which a programmer may effectuate certain functions within a program, — i.e., express the idea embodied in a given subroutine — efficiency concerns may so narrow the practical range of choice as to make only one or two forms of expression workable options. See 3 Nimmer § 13.03[F][2], at 13-63; see also Whelan, 797 F.2d at 1243 n. 43 ("It is true that for certain tasks there are only a very limited number of file structures available, and in such cases the structures might not be copyrightable. . . ."). ... It follows that in order to determine whether the merger doctrine precludes copyright protection to an aspect of a program's structure that is so oriented, a court must inquire **"whether the use of this particular set of modules is necessary efficiently to implement that part of the program's process" being implemented. [] If the answer is yes, then the expression represented by the programmer's choice of a specific module or group of modules has merged with their underlying idea and is unprotected. []**